# google maps api v3 route changing destination with a known road by itself

Tags: google-maps-api-3, routes

How can I prevent directionsService.route from changing my destination, which is in the format of latitude longitude, to the nearest known address? It is strange because in the route that the api draws, passes from the road i want, an unknown road, and goes a full circle to stop to a known address. When i try the same thing on google maps page it stops where i want and when i select the "Search nearby" option inside the infowindow it puts a marker on that same spot (address). I am doing this for driving directions.

Comment: Can you provide coordinates that cause the behavior (or an example map/jsfiddle that does)?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here is the code. The red marker is the destination. jsfiddle.net/bujar/rppDe and here is the map http://maps.google.gr/maps?saddr=Keratsini,+Pireas&daddr=37.968468,+23.766233&hl=en&sll=37.081682,23.503568&sspn=2.528444,5.410767&geocode=FTZAQwIdH2NoASll1mmkU7qhFDFgf7niLL0ABA%3BFVRaQwId2aRqAQ&t=h&mra=ls&z=13, B is the right destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string into the directions service (it contains coordinates, but is treated differently than a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)).  If you want to pass in coordinates, you need to pass in a google.maps.LatLng object, not a string:

Change:

```
var request = {
    origin: "37.962200, 23.615602",
    destination: "37.968468, 23.766233",
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

To:

```
var request = {
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(37.962200, 23.615602),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(37.968468, 23.766233),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

[modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4HEtX/2/)

[v3 directions call using the addresses from the google map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=%2837.968468,%2023.766233%29&addr2=Keratsini,%20Pireas&geocode=1&geocode=2)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea.